# 3D WPF - Как получить длину контура секущей плоскости по 3D модели?

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, 3d

Приложение `C# WPF`. Нужно загрузить 3d скан модели человека в формате `.obj` и измерить обхват талии по этой 3D модели. Вопросов с загрузкой и отображением 3d в WPF у меня не возникает. Загрузить и покрутить 3d это не сложно.

То есть сделать вот [такое](https://youtu.be/hRBebRJgtHQ) я знаю как.

1. Но вот как создать плоскость сечения 3D объекта, я не знаю. Как я понимаю в WPF это сделать не реально. По идее мне нужно получить плоскость сечения в области 3d модели и работать с этой плоскостью уже как с 2d. Можете посоветовать куда смотреть, может какой-то движок игровой нужно использовать?
2. Второе нужно сделать ручки масштаба, привязкой к линии талии. Две ручки масштаба по обе стороны талии. Как бы пользователь может растягивать или сжимать талию за них. Перерисовывать 3d не нужно. Просто в поле GUI отображаться изменения размера.Как двигать 2D объекты я представляю. Например как показано в этом [уроке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhQGqxxNLCY&list=PLt4buRcFF8pM5uTpr_HCAp3wk-9BbzGUo&index=2&t=4006s). А вот как совместить это с 3D моделью даже не представляю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]